# Installing udisks2 ejects sdcard

Tags: debian, chroot, sd-card, udisks

When installing udisks2 package on debian stable (using apt), at the "setting up" step, the sdcard gets ejected.

The problem is, the process is running from the sdcard (chroot environment).

I get the following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to fsync updated status of udisks2: Input/Output error
Bus error
```

Comment: I would think that the udisk2 package is supporting the filesystem running on the sdcard. When the package is updated, I'm guessing that it has to unmount the filesystems it is supporting in order to update itself.